# Wishlist empty after sharing

Tags: wishlist

I`m on Magento 1.9 and have a strange issue.
When I share my wishlist via email, it says; wishlist saved, and below; wishlist empty.

When I open up the email and click the link to the wishlist, it`s also empty.

What gives?